# How can I use the same wildcard in different parts of a command?

Tags: scripts, wildcards

Say I have the following command which creates a symbolic link from one file to another giving the link the same name without the extension.

```
sudo ln -s ~/foobar/abc.sh ~/fubar/abc
```

How can I do the same thing, but for `~/foobar/*.sh`?

Comment: Likely the sudo is unnecessary here.  Using sudo when it isn't needed will eventually cause you problems.

Answer (score 3):

Renaming files, and in your case, creating symlinks, `mmv` will suffice.

```
mmv -s '~/foobar/*.sh' '~/fubar/#1'
```

- `-s` For the resulting link to aim back at the source, either the source name must begin with a '/', or the target must reside in either the current or the source directory. If none of these conditions are met, the link is refused. However, source and target can reside on different devices and the source can be a directory.

Answer (score 2):

```
for fn in ~/foobar/*.sh ; do
sudo ln -s $fn ~/fubar/`basename $fn .sh`
done
```

This assumes that none of the `*.sh` files has spaces if the filename. If it does, you need to quote both arguments to `ln -s` command:

```
for fn in ~/foobar/*.sh ; do
sudo ln -s "$fn" "~/fubar/`basename $fn .sh`"
done
```

Comment: @steeldriver the OP wants to create symlinks in **different** directory. Therefore I used `basename`. Your command doesn't do it.

Comment: Oops... spelling > me